# fast key rates hosing my Java Swing application, how can I drop events early in the pipeline?

Tags: java, swing, events

Some operating systems generate keyPressed events more quickly than my application can handle them. My first thought was to not perform the action if the calls are too close together, with something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(now - lastCall < 150) {
        System.out.println("dropping event");
    }
    else {
        lastCall = now;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately despite the event dropping, the application still locks up and builds up tons of events in the queue. Is there a way I can drop events at a lower level? I think by the time they get to my action listener above, it's too late to save the application from locking up.
Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I should also mention that the listener is part of an AbstractAction that is associated with a menu item.

Comment: Is there a reason that your application cannot handle the keyPressed events?  Are you doing a long-running action in your event handler?  It would be helpful to be able to see what your event handling code looks like as well.

Comment: See my comment below to Brian Agnew. Even if I replace the entire "action" with a single print line, the behavior still occurs. The events seem to build up in the queue and take a while to get to the handler. By the time they get there the locking has already occured, and having fast action code, or dropping/coalescing events doesn't seem to matter!

Comment: Can you reproduce the locking behaviour in a minimalistic example?  What is the operating system showing this behaviour?

Comment: You need to describe what you are doing that can cause this massive flood of events

Comment: just holding down they key binding! right arrow in my app moves a progress bar forward, so users happily hold it down.

Comment: Hi here is a minimalistic example that can be compiled: http://pastebin.com/m307cdf5
The default keyrate on Windows 7 is enough to replicate the problem for me. On Mac I have to turn up the keyrate in system preferences to the highest setting. In Ubuntu 10.11 the defaults are fast enough too.
Thanks for your help.
(Btw the % 10 line is just so the printing doesn't cause its own clog.)

Comment: I really don't think action key bindings were optimized for this use-case.  What is the action being performed that the user would want to hold the key down?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this actually helps, but maybe you should do it like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    e.consume();
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(now - lastCall < 150) {
        System.out.println("dropping event");
    }
    else {
        lastCall = now;
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume()

Comment: I like the idea, but consume() is protected!

Comment: Although I could conceivably use a KeyListener instead of an AbstractAction, since consume() is public for KeyEvents. I'd like to avoid that however since the action is associated nicely with a menu item, but it's an avenue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is unable to respond in time to keypresses, I would take the time-consuming section out-of-band and process in a separate thread.

Then you can build a queue of keypresses and bin duplicates etc. if required, or perform other intelligent filtering on it. This is all application specific, but the core of it seems to be that you have heavy-duty processing in your GUI event processing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The code being run in actionPerformed really isn't intensive at all. In fact even if replace it all with one print line it still happens.
 Even if I cahnge the coalescing time in the code above to 1000 milliseconds, the program still hangs. On the other hand, if you hit the key as fast as you can (say 10 times a second), it runs fine. The events are taking too long to get to the action listener, by the time they get there the pipes are already "clogged" and dropping the event like in the code above doesn't help. :-\